# Email Validation does not working with Samsung Galaxy Edge 6 (SM-G925F)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, email-validation, samsung-galaxy

I have following code to check Email Validation which does not working in Samsung Galaxy Edge 6 (SM-G925F).

It's have Android OS `5.1.1`

```
boolean isValid=false;
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
```

which give me `false` with my email input as `namereddy05@gmail.com`

What's can be reason for such mobile specific issue .

I have also try below solution .

```
String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
```

which also give me false for valid email like `name09@gmail.com`.

Comment: It's probably more relevant which version of Android the phone is running, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's Android 5.1.1 , One of user report this that he always get invalid email popup in app for login .